# Single quotes and variables inside a bourne shell

Tags: shell, find, solaris

I have this command that I'm trying to execute in the bourne shell for Solaris 9.

```
find ${DATADIR} -name "check_*" -type f -exec sh -c '$0 | ${PARSEDATA}' {} \; >> ${TMP_1}
```

My problem is, the variable `${PARSEDATA}` won't work properly, I have tried using double quotes around it, then the problem is `$0` is the name of the script executing this code, not the file located using the `find` command.

Any suggestions to solve this, probably easy problem, is greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** `$0` is the name of the script located using the `find` command, the variable for `${PARSEDATA}` is a filter, located somewhere on the system that modifies the output of each located script. However, the problem is, I can't seem to get both `$0` and `${PARSEDATA}` to expand properly, either `$0` expands fine using single quotes, or using double qoutes `${PARSEDATA}` expands fine, but then `$0` becomes the name of the orginal script that runs this `find`-command.

Comment: It would help if you explain what you expect this command to achieve, especially the $0 and PARSEDATA stuff.

Comment: @jlliagre, Clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do? But if you want to look for scripts named check_* and then run it and pipe it through a program ${PARSE_DATA}, well I guess the file located by find is not `$0` but `{}`

Example

> find /var/ftp/mp3 -name "*.mp3" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; (Wikipedia)

So I think you can use your double quotes :

```
find ${DATADIR} -name "check_*" -type f -exec sh -c '{} | ${PARSEDATA}' \; >> ${TMP_1}
```

I've tried successfully :

```
PG='sed s/Blah/Bleh/'
find . -name "check_*" -type f -exec sh -c "{} | $PG" \;

> Bleh Blah
```

Comment: Have you checked so `sh` is simply not a symlink towards `bash` and that you're not using a GNU `find`?

Comment: Hummmm in fact, it's a symlink to /bin/dash... what is the point of calling it sh then. Damn it. But seems to be GNU find by the way.

Comment: Oh, just by curiosity : what does my example do on your pure sh?

Comment: It's because there *must* be a `/bin/sh` binary that is compatible with Bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the single quotes, the issue is very likely you haven't exported the PARSEDATA variable.

```
export PARSEDATA
find ${DATADIR} -name "check_*" -type f -exec sh -c '$0 | ${PARSEDATA}' {} \; >> ${TMP_1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want $0 to not be expanded by the shell (using single quotes) and ${PARSEDATA} be expanded, then why not just use different quotes for each:

```
find ${DATADIR} -name "check_*" -type f -exec sh -c '$0 | '"${PARSEDATA}" {} \; >> ${TMP_1}
```

As long as you keep the quoted parts joined, the shell will just expand ${PARSEDATA} and pass the whole command as a single token to find.